# org mode table row number grow automatically?

Tags: org-mode

recently I am using table to do some statistics, and I want the first column of the table to indicate the row number, as this.

```
   |  | title|
   |--| -----|
   | 1| A    |
   | 2| B    |
```

and I want the number of first column grow automatically after creating a new row.

Are there good suggestions about it?

Comment: Place `#+tblfm: $1=@#-1` under the table. Now when you move your mouse to the formula and `C-c C-c` on it, it will recalculate the contents of the first column s.a. to create a sequence of increasing integers.

Comment: wooo, great....

Comment: I was looking for exactly the same thing (@#). Sometimes searching is faster than asking... ;-D

Comment: It's possible, but time-consuming, to figure this out from the manual by piecing together info from two sections (sometimes asking is faster than searching, reading, and thinking :) Go to the info-mode manual in emacs (`C-h I`), Section 3.5.1 of the manual, in an unnumbered sub-section called "Field coordinates in formulas," explains `@#-1`. Then section 3.5.6, "Column Fomulas," explains the `$1=`.

Comment: Note that with @wvxvw's answer you can have 0-based indexing with `$1=@#-2`.

Comment: @wvxvw Still fantastic comment, 9 years later!! Question: it is possible to have half-integer increments: 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5,...? Maybe I should post this as a question...

Comment: @wvxvw Found it! Just need to multiply by 0.5 after the `=`: `#+tblfm: $1=0.5 * @#-1` :)

Answer (score 34):

Press S-ENTER in the first column after having put in '1' or another number and it will auto-increment in a new row. Not quite as clever as a formula, but is easier (for me) to remember.

Comment: wvxvw's Aug 12 '15 answer is more generally powerful because it re-numbers all the rows if I insert a row someplace in the table, or if I cut and paste a group of rows.

Comment: This is neat! Thanks.